# UserControl doesn't display the values of the exposed controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="StratPlan.Main.UserCons.WebUserControl1" %>

<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>title: </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TitleTextBox" runat="server"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>strategy id: </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="StrategyIdTextBox" runat="server"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>company: </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CompanyTextBox" runat="server"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

In its code behind:

```
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TitleTextBox.Text = ExpTitle;
        StrategyIdTextBox.Text = ExpStrategyId;
        CompanyTextBox.Text = ExpCompany;
    }

    public string ExpTitle
    {
        get { return this.TitleTextBox.Text; }
    }

    public string ExpStrategyId
    {
        get { return this.StrategyIdTextBox.Text; }
    }

    public string ExpCompany
    {
        get { return this.CompanyTextBox.Text; }
    }

}
```

Then in my page, I have a list view:

```
<div>
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <uc1:WebUserControl1 runat="server" ID="WebUserControl1" ExpStrategyId='<%# Bind(StrategyId) %>' ExpTitle='<%# Bind(Title) %>' ExpCompany='<%# Bind(CompanyName) %>'/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</div>
```

And I bind the datasource like this in code behind:

```
public void LoadGridView()
{
    localVm.EntityList = localVm.RetrieveMany(localVm.SearchItem);
    ItemsGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    ListView1.DataSource = localVm.EntityList;
    ListView1.DataBind();
}
```

But whenever I go to my page, it doesn't give the value to the user control. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pages `Load` event is called before data bound controls are bound to their data. Change it to `PreRenderComplete` or `Render` like this

```
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TitleTextBox.Text = ExpTitle;
        StrategyIdTextBox.Text = ExpStrategyId;
        CompanyTextBox.Text = ExpCompany;
    }
    ...
}
```

have a look at [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)